# firebase-toolsインストールの際のエラー

Tags: macos, node.js, firebase

firebase-toolsインストールのため、macのターミナルでコマンドを打ち込んでいます。
ドットインストールの動画（[firebase-toolsをインストールしよう](https://dotinstall.com/lessons/hosting_firebase/46104)）を参考に行なっています。

動画の通りにコマンドを打っていますが、途中でエラーが出て進めません。

①管理者権限でインストールするためにログイン→できる
②firebaseのツールがインストールされたかの確認のために
`$ firebase -V`
と打つと、
`firebase-tools update check failed`・・・
と、エラーが出ます。
スクリーンショットは以下です。
[image: ターミナルの画面]

自分で検索したり読んでみたのですが、何かのファイルが開けないのかな？と感じるだけで、解決方法がわかりません。

無知ですみませんが、ご教授いただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

仰る通り、
firebase-tools.jsonを開くアクセス権がないとなってますので、

四角く囲まれた
エラーメッセージの水色のところを試されてどうでしょうか？

Comment: できました！！初歩的な質問に答えてくださってありがとうございます！コメントに書かないでくださいと書いてありましたが、感謝です。